# Is there a way to change the passwords of all the nodes in a neo4j causal cluster?

Tags: neo4j

I have tried using curl to change the password :

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -d '{"password":"new_password"}' -u neo4j:old_password http://core_server1_ip:10003/user/neo4j/password

but I had to do it for each node, separately.

Edit : I'm using neo4j enterprise 3.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native auth provider store user's information in a file located here : `NEO4J_HOME/data/dbms/auth`, and each node has its own.

So to change the password of a user, yes you have to do it on each node.

If you want to do it just once, there is some solutions explained in the documentation : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/propagate-users-and-roles/

> To propagate changes to native users, custom roles, and role
>   assignments across a cluster, there are three options:
>
> Manually copy users and roles files on disk to all other cluster
>   instances Use a shared network folder to store users and roles files
>   Create an automated process that synchronizes the stored data across
>   the cluster using, for example, a combination of rsync and crontab We
>   note that the recommended solution for clustered security is to use
>   the LDAP or plugin auth provider.

Cheers